# When to use ajax setup exactly?

Tags: jquery

When and what is the best way to use Ajax setup? I've gone through the Jquery website. But, its a bit confusing me. I usually use simple Ajax function in my JS. Does Ajax setup has important functionality?

Regards
Nizam

Answer (score 1):

> Does Ajax setup has important functionality?

**NO**, it is not.

From the documentation

> Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is not recommended.

When you have some default setting for all over the application, you use [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/). otherwise  [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

If you want to set your `default url` or `content type` or any other setting for any future ajax request that you don't want to set each `$.ajax` request then you should use `$.ajaxSetup` to set the default value.

But in practical we rarely use the default setting through `$.ajaxSetup`. It would be dangerous if you set some wrong value in `$.ajaxSetup` then rest of your ajax request will be messed up.

Answer (score -1):

Usually Ajax is used to call the Web Services methods.

sample code

```
jQuery.ajax({    
    url: "userdetails.aspx/AddDetails",  
    type: "POST",                     
    data: jsonData,                   
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) 
        {   
    alert(data.d);
    ,
    error: function()
    {
    alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: I know that Ajax is used for calling web services or any URL. But, when Ajax setup is used and why?

Comment: Ajax shorthand for "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML," is a web development technique for creating interactive web applications. The intent is to make web pages feel more responsive by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes, so that the entire web page does not have to be reloaded each time the user requests a change. This is intended to increase the web page's interactivity, speed, and usability.
Source(s):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX

Comment: I know what Ajax means.. I'm asking you "Ajax Setup". Ajax function and Ajax setup are different.

Comment: using ajaxsetup is not recommended. why because It sets default values for all future Ajax requests.

Comment: if its not recommended, why its there in the documentation?